# Manipulating vertex groups of instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it currently possible? I can't find a way to (for example) move part of geometry (instanced using object info node) by using it's vertex groups. Connecting anything to "selection" socket doesnt display the vertex groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to consider the following things:

- A vertex group must exist in the referenced object.
- The name of the vertex group must be transferred to the geometry nodes via an input as a *Boolean* value.
- The vertex group included in this way can then be used with all nodes that have the input *Selection*.
- The selection is also always applied to the currently addressed object, which is why the object must also have a vertex group with this name.

[image]